How do I add border around my focused input in date-picker react-native?
I am building a date-picker I am using "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "8.0.1", I want to add a border around my focused input only like this: enter image description here
but it is adding the border around whole component like a box . I only want it around the middle one which is grey by-default.
my code is this I tried adding border by style, text style but it is adding it around whole component.
I want to add border like the picture but don't know how to add it
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker';

const TimePickerScreen: React.FC = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", backgroundColor: "#1A1B1E" }}>
      <DateTimePicker
        testID="timePicker"
        value={new Date()}
        mode="time"
        is24Hour={true}
        display="spinner"
        onChange={() => {}}
        textColor="white"
        style={{ flex: 1, width: "100%" }}
      />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default TimePickerScreen;


The only solution I found was to add an extra View as a border.
<View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
   <DateTimePicker
        testID="timePicker"
        value={new Date()}
        mode="time"
        is24Hour={true}
        display="spinner"
        onChange={() => {}}
        textColor="white"
      />
    <View style={{backgroundColor: 'white', width: 2, height: ' 100%'}} />
</View>


No, this doesn’t add a border around the focused input. I’m not referring to the entire container displaying all the inputs, but specifically to the one in the middle.
https://i.sstatic.net/OlTZCHL1.png
